# how to change "text" to "text field" when clicking a button in Flutter

Tags: flutter

There is a regular "Text" and it changes to "TextField" when I click the button I would like to know how to do this

```
IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.edit,
                        color: Color(0xFF8D8D8D),
                      ),
                      onPressed: null),
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isTextFild = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            isTextFild ? TextField() : Text('some text'),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Show Text Field'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isTextFild = true;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough, a `TextFormField` that toggles between `readOnly` and not. This way, you'll ensure that your view doesn't "jump" by switching widgets and you'll be always using the same object, only toggling properties.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isEditing = false;

  void _edit() {
    setState(() => _isEditing = true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      readOnly: _isEditing,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  bool _editMode = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      _editMode ? TextField(...) : Text(...),
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _editMode = !_editMode;
            });
          })
    ]);
  }
}
```

Note: If you want to set an initial value for textfield you should use textformfield instead.